# Can you polarize covariance for arbitrary distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\vec X$ be a multivariate random variable with vector of means $\vec \mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Write $\hat{\Sigma} := \frac{1}{\det \Sigma}\Sigma$ for a normalized version of the covariance matrix.

I'm interested in whether there exists an operation (hopefully algebraic, for example multiplication/squaring) $f$ which *polarizes* $\hat{\Sigma}$, meaning increases the gap between $\sigma_1(\hat{\Sigma})$ and $\sigma_2(\hat{\Sigma})$, or if you view $\hat{\Sigma}$ as defining an ellipsoid, an operation which makes this ellipsoid "less spherical" / "more pointy". Note that this operation should be a single operation that works for arbitrary covariance matrices $\hat{\Sigma}$ (if $f$ could depend on $\hat{\Sigma}$, linear transformations would work).

Is such an operation known?

Comment: A rather trivial answer would be (assuming zero mean to start with) $Y=diag(\Sigma) X$

Comment: Doesn't that require knowledge of $\Sigma$? I specifically want something that works for any covariance matrix $\Sigma$, i.e. does not itself depend on $\Sigma$ in any way.